Request help in algebraic equation for framing a business logic
Need help to find Y from the below equation
X-(1-Y*100)) = Z
If above is the formula/expression for finding Z, what is the formula for finding Y;
How can the above formula be reframed as Y =
Also, if Z is to be increased by 5%, then by what percentage should Y be increased?
Can you kindly help with this equation.
Thanks a lot for your support in advance

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

$T:=X-1$ being fixed, your equation is (equivalent to) $100Y+T=Z$. Show some attempt(s) to solve it for $Y$.
